# Ternary tree and max heap - How does it work visually?

Tags: tree, heap

I have a set of numbers I want to insert: (left to right)

> **61, 49, 90, 76, 46, 1, 82, 44, 62 ,79**

Can anyone please show how it looks visually with a tree, I fail to follow after inserting 82 to the heap.

61

61 49

90 49 61

90 49 61 76

90 49 61 76 46

90 49 61 76 46 1

90 82 61 76 46 1 49

90 82 61 76 46 1 49 44

90 82 62 76 46 1 49 44 61

90 82 79 76 46 1 49 44 61  62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a ternary heap, each node has up to three children. The heap is represented in the array in breadth-first order, with the root node at 0, and the children of node x at locations `(x*3)+1`, `(x*3)+2`, and `(x*3)+3`. The node at location x is at `(x-1)/3`.

So, your array, `[90,82,79,76,46,1,49,44,61,62]`, looks like this when displayed the simple way.

```
92
 |- 82
     |- 46
     |- 1
     |- 49
 |- 79
     |- 44
     |- 61
     |- 62
 |--76
```

Or, more traditionally:

```
              92
        /      |     \
    82        79         76
  / | \      / | \
46  1 49   44 61 62
```

You might find my discussion of the [d-ary heap](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/10/05/the-d-ary-heap/) useful.

Comment: I read this at wiki `(x*3)+1`, `(x*3)+2`, and `(x*3)+3`, and I didn't use it. Now I did, and I understood it well. Thanks Jim!